# Cardinality violation: 1241 when using mysql group by if and case

Tags: mysql, if-statement, group-by

I am getting Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) when I use two column with `,` in group by.

```
        SELECT 
        s.id,
        s.order_id,
        IF(so.collection_id!=0,SUM(s.od_dis_total),s.od_dis_total) as od_dis_total,
        s.od_dis_gst,
        s.order_discount,
        COUNT(si.product_id) as items,
        so.collection_id    
        FROM subscription s 
        LEFT JOIN subscription_items si ON si.subscription_id=s.id   
        LEFT JOIN subscribe_order_items soi ON soi.subscribe_order_id=s.subscribe_order_id 
        LEFT JOIN subscribe_orders as so ON so.id=s.subscribe_order_id 
        group By IF(so.collection_id!=0,(soi.subscribe_order_id, date(s.dated)),si.subscription_id)
```

I also tried using CASE in group by same error

```
CASE WHEN so.collection_id!=0 THEN (soi.subscribe_order_id,date(s.dated)) ELSE si.subscription_id END
```

Can someone pls help.

Comment: try to concat `soi.subscribe_order_id,date(s.dated)` into a single value

Comment: @ProGu Thanks. when I use concat it takes time to get result. Can you pls tell me how to optimize.

Comment: First step is run `EXPLAIN SELECT ....` to get execution plan. It's better if you can provide table creation scripts, sample data, expected output, etc, many people will help.

Comment: XY. Explain the meaning of this construction: `group By IF(so.collection_id!=0,(soi.subscribe_order_id, date(s.dated)),si.subscription_id)`. What groups do you want to form, by what criteria? Your task is not clear now...